# SQL - Getting count by Distinct based on Type

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: 3 Table]

I have these three different result set.

If typeId 7 is duplicated between two different Ids, then they count as two. Any TypeId other than 7, count should distinct of Ids.

First table count is 5 because Id 1 is unique between 4 & 7. Id 2 is 3 times but other than Type 7, it is distinct. So, it count as 2.

How can I write a query for this.

I tried Distinct(Id) + Distinct Iff(TypeId = 7) and of course this return wrong result.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, please post text instead. A [mcve] would be useful, please show your sample data (preferably `CREATE TABLE` `INSERT` statements) and expected output, along with what you have tried so far. `DISTINCT` is not a function (it acts over the whole resultset) so not sure what you mean by `DISTINCT (ID)`

Answer (score 1):

Count those that are not 7 distinct. (NULL isn't counted)
Then add the total unique id's of 7.

```
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TypeId = 7 THEN NULL ELSE Id END) +
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TypeId = 7 THEN Id END)
```

Comment: Not returning the count as I expected

Comment: Looks fine according [this test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=07865b17951402a0c947a3c783caa998). Not sure what else you expect.

Comment: @Chatra Then show what results you expect instead of a paragraph, please.